# How to select two columns from awk and print if they do not match

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I need to select two MSISDN values from OMO account Migration logs and print the ones that do not match.

```
[2019-03-11 04:15:08 INFO-SUBAPP ESBRestClient:117] ## IP-103.228.158.85##TOKEN-201903110416276787774(**923419606907**)RESPONSE-BODY: {"callStatus":"false","responseCode":"18","description":"OMO account migration – **923481057772**"}
[2019-03-11 04:24:02 INFO-SUBAPP ESBRestClient:117] ## IP-119.153.134.128##TOKEN-1552260212780839(923214748517)RESPONSE-BODY: {"callStatus":"false","responseCode":"18","description":"OMO account migration – 953214748517"}
```

`923481057772` is the old MSISDN.

`923419606907` is the new MSISDN and I need to save it in a new file. I'm was using the following command to select only the new MSISDN:

```
cat migration.txt | egrep "OMO account migration" | egrep "responseCode\":\"1700" | awk -F"(" '{gsub(/\).*/,"",$2);print $2}' >>newmsisdn.txt
```

I'm using the saved msisdn values to fetch the token number. Then I'm using those tokens to fetch multiple parameters. Final output is something like this:

```
Date            Time          Old MSISDN        New MSISDN     Old Profile New Profile  CNIC      Acc Status Acc Status Migration Channel
                                                                                                   (Before)   (After)
2019-03-11  |  00:00:14  |  923135260528  |  923029403541  |  OMO BVS MA  |  0  |  1620221953175  |  ACTIVE  |     |  subapp

2019-03-11  |  00:00:14  |  923135260528  |  923003026654  |  OMO BVS MA  |  0  |  1620221953175  |  ACTIVE  |     |  subapp

2019-03-11  |  00:00:14  |  923135260528  |  923003026654  |  OMO BVS MA  |  0  |  1620221953175  |  ACTIVE  |     |  subapp

2019-03-11  |  00:00:14  |  923135260528  |  923038048244  |  OMO BVS MA  |  0  |  1620221953175  |  ACTIVE  |     |  subapp
```

In the second log instance, these two values are the same. I need to filter those out i.e. I only need to use the non matching values.
How do I compare the two non matching values and print the new MSISDN?

Comment: When you say `filter those out` do you mean `print those lines` or `print all except those lines` or something else? [edit] your question to show multiple lines of input, not just one, some that do and some that don't match your criteria, and also the expected output given that input.

Comment: I need to print all lines except the ones with same MSISDNs. Actually, with the new MSISDN, I need to fetch the token number. And with that token number, I will extract multiple parameters. I'll post the output as well.

Comment: Sana, if you want to get best and most helpful answers, you should follow @EdMorton's advice including, for example, showing "multiple lines of input, not just one, some that do and some that don't match your criteria."  Only you know what your actual input looks like. Without clear & precise data from you, we can only guess and guessing can waste our time and yours.

Answer (score 5):

## Answer for first version of the question

Try:

```
awk -F'[*][*]' '/OMO account migration/ && /responseCode":"18"/ && $2 != $4 { print $2}' migration.txt
```

The avoids the need for spawning multiple processes and connecting them with pipelines.  That makes this approach comparatively efficient.

#### How it works

- `-F'[*][*]'`

  This sets the field separator to be two stars.  In this way the new MSISDN is field 2 and the old one is field 4.
- `/OMO account migration/ && /responseCode":"18"/ && $2 != $4 { print $4}`

  This selects for lines which (1) contain the regex `OMO account migration/` **and** (2) contain the regex `responseCode":"18"` **and** (3) have the second field different from the fourth.  For any such line, the second field is printed.

#### Example

Let's consider this three-line test file:

```
$ cat migration.txt 
[2019-03-11 04:15:08 INFO-SUBAPP ESBRestClient:117] ## IP-103.228.158.85##TOKEN-201903110416276787774(**923419606907**)RESPONSE-BODY: {"callStatus":"false","responseCode":"18","description":"OMO account migration – **923481057772**"}
[2019-03-11 04:15:08 INFO-SUBAPP ESBRestClient:117] ## IP-103.228.158.85##TOKEN-201903110416276787774(**923419606888**)RESPONSE-BODY: {"callStatus":"false","responseCode":"19","description":"OMO account migration – **923481057999**"}
[2019-03-11 04:15:08 INFO-SUBAPP ESBRestClient:117] ## IP-103.228.158.85##TOKEN-201903110416276787774(**923419606123**)RESPONSE-BODY: {"callStatus":"false","responseCode":"18","description":"OMO account migration – **923419606123**"}
```

Let's run our command:

```
$ awk -F'[*][*]' '/OMO account migration/ && /responseCode":"18"/ && $2 != $4 {print $2}' migration.txt >>newmsisdn.txt
```

The output file now contains the one new MSISDN that we want:

```
$ cat newmsisdn.txt 
923419606907
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples and you need new value for each line, if this is the case then try following.

```
awk '
/OMO account migration/ && /responseCode":"18"/{
  val_old=val_new=""
  match($0,/\*\*[0-9]+\*\*/)
  val_old=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  match($0,/\*\*[0-9]+\*\*/)
  val_new=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
(val_old!=val_new){
  gsub("*","",val_new)
  print val_new
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                                     ##Starting awk program here.
/OMO account migration/ && /responseCode":"18"/{          ##Checking condition if a line contains strings OMO account migration AND responseCode":"18" in it then do following.
  val_old=val_new=""                                      ##Nullifying variables val_old and val_new here.
  match($0,/\*\*[0-9]+\*\*/)                              ##Using match OOTB function of awk to match from **digits** here. If match found then value of RSTART and RLENGTH(awk variables) will be SET.
  val_old=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                       ##Creating variable val_old which is substring of starting point as RSTART and ending point of RLENGTH here.
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                            ##Re-defining value of current line with substring whose value starts after matched regexs next index, so that we can catch new value in next further statements.
  match($0,/\*\*[0-9]+\*\*/)                              ##Using match OOTB function of awk to match from **digits** here. If match found then value of RSTART and RLENGTH(awk variables) will be SET(2nd time run).
  val_new=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                       ##Creating variable named val_new whose value is substring of current line startpoint is RSTART and ending point is RLENGTH here.
}                                                         ##Closing BLOCK for string matching condition here.
(val_old!=val_new){                                       ##Checking condition ig val_old variable is NOT equal to val_new then do following.
  gsub("*","",val_new)                                    ##Globaly subsituting * in val_new to get exact value as per OP need.
  print val_new                                           ##Printing val_new value here.
}
'  Input_file                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @SANA SIDDIQUI, could you please check this and let me know if this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the following approach : I see that every MSISDN number contains twelve digits ([0-9]), located between two double asterisks.
You can find those using following regular expression:

```
grep -o "\*\*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\*\*"
```

In case your system supports this, you might simplify this to:

```
grep -o "\*\*[0-9]{12}\*\*"
```

Once you have those, you might use `awk` for showing just the ones being different, something like:

```
'{IF ($1 != $2) PRINT $1 $2}' (not tested).
```